# Relay component to schematic, are these the same?

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, eaglecad, solid-state-relay

I'm new to PCB designing and schematics and have chosen this component from the eagle library as it said G5l and showed a similar component to the one i have, but the terminals donit appear to look in the right orientation as seen below, however i did my best to connect them.

So is this a correct representation of my component?
and if yes is it correctly connected?

[image: My Current Relay Schematic]

[image: The Component I have]

Comment: What is your component? Seems to be a four pin thingy.

Comment: It's a five-pin thingy.  Three on the left, two on the right.

Comment: probably one of these G5LE-1 G5LE-1A

Comment: 2 pins for relay coil, 3 pins for switch (NO,COM,NC)

Comment: Confused by the question. Are you asking about the symbol on the schematic or the pin-out of the actual device? If it's the former see @JBH 's answer. If it's the pin-out check the data-sheet carefully, those 5-pin relays have different configurations depending on the model.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you have it all hooked up correctly, but it's not the kind of symbol I'm used to seeing.

[image]

That's more what I'm familiar with.  A solid-state version would show the box-with-a-diagonal-like like you have rather than a solenoid.  Your's seems to have split the switch portion and the "solenoid" potion apart.  Kinda confusing if you ask me.

Comment: you are correct thats the symbol im looking for, but i cant seem to find it in my libraries, do you know where i can get this library from ?

Comment: What tool are you using to draw your schematics?

Comment: Eagle Autodesk PCB design software

Comment: Regrettably, I have no experience with the product.  You appear to be using a manufacturer-specific symbol.  See if there is a generic library (I'm sure there is one) or look for a generic 5-port relay symbol.  If you can't find one, I suggest a quick visit to the [Eagle Support Forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/bd-p/3500) where you'll find experienced users who will be better prepared to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using Eagle or any PCB Designing software in the future, one thing I'd recommend doing is to learn how to create your own library.

Talking about the above problem, I'd suggest you find a decent tutorial on Youtube, and make the component footprint and symbol on your own.

It would be time consuming initially but it is worth the effort as this would be a one-time exercise. After few projects, you might need to create very less or no components for the new project.

Comment: I had a quick look through the eagle libraries and all the relay schematic symbols look pretty crap. Very similar to the OP's image. Another thing you can do is edit the existing symbol for the G5L, as long as the PCB layout stays the same and you make sure to match up the pins you shouldn't have a problem

Comment: @Doodle: Yes a good point you added there. You can edit a component if that's an easier thing to do or make it from scratch. That is your decision to make. Whatever saves time!